# Variable in function python

Tags: python

i have a little problem with my code.
How can i make global variable in my code and functions?
Example in my project ( it's simple game ) i want have a wallet - so its must be a global to earn and lose gold. In this code player is in minigame and can lose or earn more money but I would like this wallet to be variable throughout the file and react along with the minigame and other things in the code.
How to do it correctly?

````
leave_action = 'n'
print("Welcome in dice poker.")
while leave_action.lower() != 'y':
    wallet = 5
    bounty_from_dice = 0
    if wallet == 0:
        leave_action = input("Do you want leave from table? \nY. \nN. \n")
    bet = int(input("Ile chcesz postawic? "))
    wallet = wallet - bet
    dice = sorted([ri(1, 6) for _ in range(5)])
    print(dice)
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'{i + 1} throw a dice, the drawn value is {dice[i]} ')
    result = pair(dice)
    result2 = triple(dice)
    resultf = full(dice)
    resultp = poker(dice)
    resultk = kareta(dice)
    resultss = smallstreet(dice)
    if result:
        print('PAIR!')
        bounty_from_dice = bounty_from_dice + 1
    else:
        print('No pair here')
    if result2:
        print('FAIR!')
        bounty_from_dice = bounty_from_dice + 2
    else:
        print('No fair here')
    if resultf:
        print("FULL!")
        bounty_from_dice = bounty_from_dice + 5
    else:
        print("No FULL here")
    if resultk:
        print("KARETA!")
        bounty_from_dice = bounty_from_dice + 5
    else:
        print("No kareta here")
    if resultp:
        print("POKER!")
        bounty_from_dice = bounty_from_dice + 10
    else:
        print("No poker here")
    if resultss:
        print("Smallstreet!")
        bounty_from_dice = bounty_from_dice + 15
    else:
        print("No smallstreet here")
    hazard_award = bounty_from_dice * int(bet)
    wallet = wallet + hazard_award
    print("Your win ratio is : " + str(bounty_from_dice))
    print("You won from dice poker : " + str(hazard_award))
    leave_action = input("Do you want leave from table? \nY. \nN. \n")
    print("Your current gold: " + str(wallet))
    if leave_action == 'y':
        print("You left from dice poker.")
    ```
````

Comment: In your code, `wallet ` already is a global variable. Question unclear.

Comment: You create `wallet` in the while loop, but it still exists after the while loop. Though if the code you shared is within a function, wallet doesn't exist outside of that function.

Comment: If the code that you posted is inside a function, put the line `global wallet` at the top of the function. If that doesn't solve it -- you really need to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code you shared is within a function, you can do multiple things to have a global wallet.

### Pass as an argument

```py
wallet = 5

def playDicePoker(wallet):
    # [your code here but without the wallet=5 line in the while loop]
    return wallet  # to recover the new wallet value

# Usage:
wallet = playDicePoker(wallet)
```

### Make it a global variable

*This will need more work if you split the code over multiple file.*

```py
global wallet
wallet = 5

def playDicePoker():
    global wallet
    # [your code here but without the wallet=5 line in the while loop]

# Usage:
playDicePoker()
# now wallet is updated
```

### Have a Player class

*This will allow you to easily store other informations about your player as well, like the number of wins, the number of game played for each game, and so on*

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, initialWallet):
        self.wallet = initialWallet

def playDicePoker(player):
    # [your code here but replacing wallet by player.wallet]
    # (also no player.wallet = 5 since it's already initialized)

# Usage:

player = Player(5)
playDicePoker(player)
```